# Would it be possible to use a Socket IO connection on multiple pages with PersistJS?

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io, persistjs

If I would store the Socket IO connection variable using something like PersistJS, would the connection and its events still work if navigating to another page and loading the Socket IO connection variable from PersistJS?

For example

- Connect using Socket IO (or WebSockets)
- Store the connection var to JS session, e.g. PersistJS
- Navigate to another page
- Load the Socket IO var from PersistJS, if it exists
- **Are the socket IO connection + events restored?**

**The purpose would be to keep the Socket IO connection active between the browsing of pages. A delay to load it again is acceptable.**

I'm guessing the events attached to Socket IO messages will be removed, or something might be wrong with the connection.

Comment: It would probably be simpler if you told us what you're trying to achieve / what your current issue is, as we probably have an XY problem here.

Comment: @jcaron The purpose is to keep a Socket IO connection active, even after browsing to another page, or reloading the specific page.

Comment: AFAIK, the only way to keep the **same** connection active is to stay on the same page, which means using Ajax to load content rather than actually navigating to a new page. But if you navigate to a new page, nothing prevents you from establishing a new connection and use some identifier (via cookies or localStorage) to re-associate the connection. So really, what is the actual problem you're trying to solve?